Making a \book block only if condition is met in lilypond
For a musical piece I want to write in Lilypond, my goal is to write each instrument part in a separate file. However, I want to have a score-block in each file to output each part individually (including midi). Additionally, I want to just include the instrument parts into the full score file to get all the needed parts.
Here are some example how this would look like:
sax_1.ly
\version "2.24.4"
\include "_global_definitions.ly"

\header {
  instrument = "Saxophone 1"
}

\paper {
  % setting paper layout here
}

melody_alto_sax_one = {
    % some actual music notation here
} 

\score {
  \layout { }
  \new Staff 
  \with {midiInstrument = "alto sax"} 
  \with { \transposition es}
  \melody_alto_sax_one 
  \midi { }
}


sax_2.ly
\version "2.24.4"
\include "_global_definitions.ly"

\header {
  instrument = "Saxophone 2"
}

\paper {
  % setting paper layout here
}

melody_alto_sax_two = {
    % some actual music notation here
} 

\score {
  \layout { }
  \new Staff 
  \with {midiInstrument = "alto sax"} 
  \with { \transposition es}
  \melody_alto_sax_two 
  \midi { }
}


full_score.ly
\version "2.24.4"

\include "_global_definitions.ly"
\include "alto_sax_one.ly"
\include "alto_sax_two.ly"

\header {
  instrument = "Full Score"
}

\paper {
    % setting paper layout here
}

\score {
  \midi { 
  }
  \layout {}
  \removeWithTag #'nobreak %I use this tag to avoid line breaks for the full score 
  <<
      \new StaffGroup = "StaffGroup_saxophones" <<
          \new Staff 
          \with {instrumentName = "Saxophone 1"} 
          \with {midiInstrument = "alto sax"} 
          \with { \transposition es}
          \melody_alto_sax_one
          \new Staff 
          \with {instrumentName = "Saxophone 2"} 
          \with {midiInstrument = "alto sax"} 
          \with { \transposition es}
          \melody_alto_sax_two
      >>
      % add other staff groups here 
  >>
}

This works fine for the most part, however it does execute the \score block for each of the musical instruments when I engrave the full score and creates/overwrites those midi files.
First I have looked for a way to insert certain parts of another .ly file, but there doesn't seem to be an option for that.
I tried to make the execution of the \score block conditional, based on a scheme variable.
The variable would be defined in _global_definitions.ly as true. At the beginning of full_score.ly I would set it to false and finally change each score block of the instrument parts to the following:
#(if make_instrument_parts 
  #{
    \score {
      \layout { }
      \new Staff 
      \with {midiInstrument = "alto sax"} 
      \with { \transposition es}
      \melody_alto_sax_one 
      \midi { }
}
  #} '()
)

This does not work however (I don't really get a useful error message, just no output - I have tested around with message output and the variable and all other values seem to be correct).
The only way I know would work for sure is to put melody_alto_sax_one in its own file and import it once for the full score and once for the instrument part. This is however quite tedious during writing the parts, since it means switching files all the time.

I don’t fully understand what your issue is, but what you are seeing is a difference between different ways to evaluate scheme code in Lilypond.
Basically # will be handled by the parser as some sort of scheme expression, with no further looking into of what it actually is. $ on the other hand will be evaluated beforehand and than handled as if it was entered.
So when you do
##{\score { { 4 4 4 } }#}

nothing happens because the parser sees this as a scheme expression, not as a score object. If you do instead

$#{\score { { 4 4 4 } }#}

the parser will first evaluate the expression and then now that it is a score and handle it accordingly.
But note that if you want to suppress scores from the individual files when included you can do
$(if (equal? input-file-name (car (ly:input-file-line-char-column (*location*))))
     #{
       \score {
         ...
       }
     #})

This checks if the current location is in the file Lilypond was called on (which will not be the case when included from a different file).

Hi, thank you for the help, I really like the idea of just checking the file location instead of using a variable. I have just one problem, I get an error unknown escaped string:\melody_alto_sax_one'`. If you remove the variable from the score block and just insert some random notes, it seems to work. It just seems like the variable is out of scope, so I have to figure this out still.

@RolandDeschain Yes, this is something that can happen. Basically the parser will not necessarily evaluate an expression instantly, as it needs to perform lookaheads. This means that when using $ a previous assignment might not yet be evaluated. This can be prevented by placing anything definite in between, such as simply #'() or something. Alternatively use a scheme function for this: conditional = #(define-scheme-function (cond what) (boolean? scheme?) (if cond what)) and then \conditional #(equal? input-file-name (car (ly:input-file-line-char-column (*location*)))) \score { ... }

Thanks so much for the help!
